# What does a=&*A mean in C++ (in which A is a pointer)?

Tags: c++, pointers

I come across this instruction

```
a=&*A;
```

in a piece of C++ code, where A is a pointer. Can anyone explain its semantics and in what way it is different from `a=A`?

Comment: C or C++? Very important difference here! (Unless everything here is built-in types. If that's the case, state it.)

Comment: Remember that C++ have operator overloading, so it's impossible to answer without knowing what `A` is and what operators are overloaded for it.

Comment: It means "stupid tricks".

Comment: follow @JoachimPileborg - is A iterator?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If `A` is an iterator, then `*A` gives you the value of what the iterator is "pointing" to. Then the `&` operator is applied to that value to get an address to the value. Unless the `&` operator was overloaded.

Simple and somewhat stupid example:

```
struct Foo
{
    // Some data...
};

std::vector<Foo> vector_of_foo;

// Code to populate vector_of_foo

for (auto A = vector_of_foo.begin(); A != vector_of_foo.end(); ++A)
{
    Foo* a = &*A;
    // Do something that requires a pointer to Foo...
}
```

Comment: The example is more than 10000 words :) Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Operator * can be overloaded, and it usually is overloaded for iterators and smart pointers.

If `A` is a class with pointer-like semantics and you want to get *raw pointer* to value it points to, then you have to apply operator* (to access value) and then operator& (to retrieve address).

This is most likely usecase when you will see construct like that. It is impossible to know more without knowing what `A` and related classes is: * can be overloaded to do something else and & can be overloaded too.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming `A` is kind of object, then probably `*` is an operator.

If `A` is say iterator, then `a` could be the address of current element where the iterator points.

Answer (score -1):

Here is the explanation which i learnt in my college.
 & = "address of"

- = "value at"

&*A = from left to right "Address of , Value at A".